# Bootstrap datepicker dropdown not dropping

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried removing and adding things but the dropdown still won't drop. I'm not sure what the problem is. I added the less files which includes the dropdown but still nothinh changed. The textbox is working though. Here's what the code looks like

```
    <html>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
              href="css/datepicker3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/dropdowns.less">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/sprites.less">
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
                 changeMonth: true;
                 changeYear: true;
        });
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
    </script>

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="js/bootstrap.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
                src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.js">
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have two bootstrap JS, if you already have `bootstrap.min.js` there is no need to include `bootstrap.js`. Because, basically they're the same, just "minified". Try adding `$(document).ready(..);` in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You custom javascript method is being executed before jquery and bootstrap.js load. Your custom method will work only when their library class loads before your method executed. So, Your code must look like this :

```
    <html>
        <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
                  href="css/datepicker3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/dropdowns.less">
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/sprites.less">
        </head>
        <body>
    <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
        </script>

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.js">
                    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function(){
      $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
});
    });

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

```js
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
            <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
              <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
              <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            </head>
            <body>
        <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
            </div>
            
            <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
              
        
            </body>
        </html>
```

Also there are no ";" but "," in datepicker options,
And as @`Sachi Tekina` said, no need to load bootstrap twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the datepicker function before importing your js files.
Also remove the line below since you are already calling the minified version.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js">
    </script>
```

There is also an extra `</script>` tag above `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Try it like this:

```
<html>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
              href="css/datepicker3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/dropdowns.less">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/sprites.less">
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.js">
     </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
                 changeMonth: true;
                 changeYear: true;
         });
       });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it but for some reason, it's still not working. Thanks though.

Comment: You are most welcomed .However try with the $(document).ready(function(){ }); Check the updated version above.
Also there is an extra </script> tag .
Also is there any errors in the console..Use firebug to find any eventual errors poping out.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
 $('.date').datepicker({
             changeMonth: true;
             changeYear: true;
    });
```

refer
  http://runnable.com/UmOlOZbXvZRqAABU/bootstrap-datepicker-example-text-input-with-specifying-date-format2